# Ember.js routing with parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I just played with [ember routing example](http://ghempton.github.com/ember-layout-example). It looks quite interesting. Especially if you are going to build all your application on Ember framework.

But parameters in url follows after `'#'`. That means you can't copy and send a link to someone if client has to login with postback (if only to set a cookie with login parameters). Is there a better option - maybe use `'?'` instead of `'#'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may also have a look at Ember.Router.
There are two good start points @ https://gist.github.com/2679013 and https://gist.github.com/2728699

A lot of fixes have been made the last couple of days.

**EDIT**

A brand new guide is now available @ https://emberjs-staging-new.herokuapp.com/guides/outlets#toc_the-router

Comment: could You recommend some tutorials or examples of managing states with controlers?

Comment: Well, in fact, it is true that the given snippets are a little bit laconic. The official documentation does not yet covers this topic, but we are currently working with all these stuff with support from Tom Dale. Maybe I could help you with a full working example: I will write down an article ASAP & notify through this question.

Comment: Yes, promising indeed. I just see there are different properties responsible for managing routes. In first example there is `setupContext` property, in second there is `setupControllers` and last has `connectOutlets`. It seems all they have very similar purpose. Should I stick to some or just have to wait till there are some more cleariness or else? And can't find out where `:post_id` parameter comes from when user clicks on certain post (last example)?

Comment: I'll second Saulius's confusion about how all this works. A fully working canonical example would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example courtesy of https://github.com/jbrown

http://jsfiddle.net/justinbrown/C7LrM/10/

Comment: Yes I saw last one either. And I believe that this must be considered as "canonical example" at the moment as there is latest ember and no additional routing libraries. And there is `connectOutlets` which is used in [ember site tutorial](https://emberjs-staging-new.herokuapp.com/guides/outlets#toc_the-router) 
It just a pity that it works with `#` which has shortcoming not being sent to server.